# Prove that for any function $g$ from $X$ into [0,1] there is a point $p $ such that $f(p)$=$g(p)$ .

Tags: general-topology

Let  $X$ be a connected space and $f$ be continuous function from $X$ onto the  closed unit interval with usual topology . Prove that for any function $g$ from $X$ into $[0,1]$ there is a point $p$  such that $f(p)=g(p)$ .

My question, how can I solve it without adding assumption that $g$ is continuous.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is " there is a point $p$ $g$ is continuous function" supposed to mean?

Comment: It is fixed, it is clear now

Comment: I have a stupid question when you say that f maps X onto the unit interval, do you mean that f has to be surjective? If yes how do you use that hypothesis to prove your statement? Can't you just define another continuous function h as the difference between f and g and use the generalised Bolzano theorem to show that h has a zero?

Answer (score 1):

this is not true take $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x$ and 
$$
g(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1-x & \textrm{ if } x\neq 1/2\\
1 & \textrm{ if } x= 1/2\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Yes, you are right